# R package for identifying relationships between variables

Tags: r, data-visualization, correlation, exploratory-data-analysis

Is there an R package that I can use to explore whether there exist relationships between variables?

Typically when I am looking for patterns I look at correlations, and then a facet plot. Then I manually apply some transformations to variables in the data. I was wondering if I could accelerate this process through an R package.

Comment: If you have your own process, you could always roll your own package. Or just a reusable function in some file loaded at the beginning of your script.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

AFAIK, no. To be more precise, I don't know of a single R package that would do part of what is called *Exploratory Data Analysis* (EDA) for you through a single function call -- I'm thinking of the *re-expression* and *revelation* aspects discussed in Hoaglin, Mosteller and Tukey, *Understanding Robust and Exploratory Data Analysis*. Wiley-Interscience, 1983, in particular.

However, there exist some nifty alternatives in R, especially regarding interactive exploration of data (Look here for interesting discussion: [When is interactive data visualization useful to use?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7048/when-is-interactive-data-visualization-useful-to-use)). I can think of

- [iplots](http://rosuda.org/iplots/), or its successor [Acinonyx](http://www.rforge.net/Acinonyx/), for interactive visualization (allowing for brushing, linked plots, and the like) (Some of these functionalities can be found in the [latticist](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/latticist/index.html) package; finally, [rgl](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgl/index.html) is great for 3D interactive visualization.)
- [ggobi](http://www.ggobi.org/) for interactive and dynamic displays, including data reduction (Multidimensional scaling) and [Projection Pursuit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_pursuit)

This is only for interactive data exploration, but I would say this is the essence of EDA. Anyway, the above techniques might help when exploring bivariate or higher-order relationships between numerical variables. For categorical data, the [vcd](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/vcd/index.html) package is a good option (visualization and summary tables). Then, I would say than the [vegan](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/vegan/index.html) and [ade4](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ade4/index.html) packages come first for exploring relationships between variables of mixed data types.

Finally, what about *data mining* in R? (Try this keyword on [Rseek](http://www.rseek.org/))

Comment: (+1) Nice to see you back answering questions!

Comment: +1 Btw: little typo - Acinonyx (i & y are transposed).

Comment: @Iterator Thanks for catching the typo. (I've already +1 your response, good that you cited Wilkinson's paper).

Comment: There's now `loon` also http://waddella.github.io/loon/  Credit goes to @hadleywickham for pointing this out.

Answer (score 11):

If you just want to get a quick look at how variables in your dataset are correlated, take a look at the pairs() function, or even better, the pairs.panels() function in the psych package. I wrote a little about the pairs function [here](http://gettinggeneticsdone.blogspot.com/2011/07/scatterplot-matrices-in-r.html).

Using the pairs() or psych::pairs.panels() function it's pretty easy to make scatterplot matrices.

```
pairs.panels(iris[-5], bg=c("blue","red","yellow")[iris$Species], pch=21,lm=TRUE)
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Check out the `scagnostics` package and the [original research paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.62.6148&rep=rep1&type=pdf).  This is very interesting for bivariate relationships.  For multivariate relationships, projection pursuit is a very good first step.

In general, though, domain and data expertise will both narrow and improve your methods for quickly investigating relationships.

Answer (score 7):

The [chart.Correlation](http://www.oga-lab.net/RGM2/func.php?rd_id=PerformanceAnalytics:chart.Correlation) function in [PerformanceAnalytics](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/PerformanceAnalytics/index.html) provides similar functionality to the plot.pairs function @Stephen Turner mentioned, except it smooths with a loess function rather than a linear model, and the significance for the correlations.

```
library(PerformanceAnalytics)
chart.Correlation(iris[-5], bg=c("blue","red","yellow")[iris$Species], pch=21)
```

[image: Chart]

Answer (score 5):

If you are looking for possible transformations to work with correlation, then a tool that has not been mentioned yet that may be useful is `ace` which can be found in the `acepack` package (and probably other packages as well).  This does an interative process of trying many different transformations (using smoothers) to find the transformations to maximize the correlation between a set of x variables and a y variable.  Plotting the transformations can then suggest meaningful transformations.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the DCOR function in the 'energy' package to compute a measure of non-linear dependency called distance correlation and plot as above. The issue with Pearson's correlation is that it can only detect linear-relationships between variables. Make sure you choose the write parameter for index in the DCOR function that said.