# Understanding coefficients in summary output of logistic regression in R

Tags: r, regression, logistic, interaction

This question is about understanding the logistic regression output using R.  Here is my sample data frame:

```
    Drugpairs             AdverseEvent  Y    N
1   Rebetol + Pegintron       Nausea   29 1006
2   Rebetol + Pegintron      Anaemia   21 1014
3   Rebetol + Pegintron     Vomiting   14 1021
4   Ribavirin + Pegasys       Nausea    5  238
5   Ribavirin + Pegasys      Anaemia   12  231
6   Ribavirin + Pegasys     Vomiting    1  242
7 Ribavirin + Pegintron       Nausea   15  479
8 Ribavirin + Pegintron      Anaemia    7  487
9 Ribavirin + Pegintron     Vomiting    9  485
```

This basically describes the number of times a particular drug pair has caused a medically adverse event. (`Y=yes, N=no`). I ran a logistic regression on this dataset in R using the following commands:

```
mod.form    = "cbind(Y,N) ~ Drugpairs * AdverseEvent"
glmhepa.out = glm(mod.form, family=binomial(logit), data=hepatitis.df)
```

The summary output was as follows (only showing the coefficients table):

```
                                                      Estimate Std. Error z value
(Intercept)                                          -3.8771     0.2205 -17.586
DrugpairsRibavirin + Pegasys                          0.9196     0.3691   2.491
DrugpairsRibavirin + Pegintron                       -0.3652     0.4399  -0.830
AdverseEventNausea                                    0.3307     0.2900   1.140
AdverseEventVomiting                                 -0.4123     0.3479  -1.185
DrugpairsRibavirin + Pegasys:AdverseEventNausea      -1.2360     0.6131  -2.016
DrugpairsRibavirin + Pegintron:AdverseEventNausea     0.4480     0.5457   0.821
DrugpairsRibavirin + Pegasys:AdverseEventVomiting    -2.1191     1.1013  -1.924
DrugpairsRibavirin + Pegintron:AdverseEventVomiting   0.6678     0.6157   1.085
```

I understand that the coefficients give probabilistic odds. I am curious however, as to why there are no coefficients for the `AdverseEventAnaemea` and also why is there no coefficient for any combination of the drugs and the adverse event anaemea? (The last 4 rows are the combination effects of drugs and adverse events)

Answer (score 2):

This is a frequently asked question.  You have an interaction of factors.  Having an interaction means that all combinations of the levels of each factor are represented, so there are 3*3=9 combinations.  If you count the rows in the summary output, you will see that there are 9 rows of output.  Factors are represented by default by dummy codes formed using reference level coding.  The first level (`DrugpairsRebetol + Pegintron:AdverseEventAnaemea` in your case) is taken as the reference level, so that level is indexed by the `(Intercept)` in your model / in the summary output.  When `DrugpairsRebetol + Pegintron` is held constant, the other two `AdverseEvents` are listed separately; when `AdverseEventAnaemea` is held constant, the other two `Drugpairs` are listed separately.  The remaining 4 combinations are indicated individually in the last 4 lines of the output.  To understand these ideas more fully, it may help you to read these:

- Interactions: [Interaction in generalized linear model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/49701/7290)
- Factors: [Regression based for example on days of week](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/21292/7290)