# How to visualize interaction effects in linear mixed models with random term?

Tags: regression, mixed-model, matlab

I am assessing the effect of a specific drug (categorical factor: 0=placebo, 1=drug1, 2=drug2) and probability differences on choice. My model in MATLAB therefore looks like that:

```
lme=fitglme(T,'choice~prob_diff+drug+drug:prob_diff+(1|subj)',
            'link','logit','Distribution','binomial','FitMethod','REMPL');
```

I get a significant interaction effect between drug and probability difference (positive tstat for drug 1 and negative tstat for drug2). As I understand this indicates that the slope for predicting choice from probability differences is higher under drug 1 (compared to drug2+placebo) and lower under drug2 (compared to drug1 and placebo).

My question is: What would be a good way to visualize the effects? I can`t just estimate a new model seperately for each drug and compare the slopes right? Because then I would miss within subject variance that is included in the full model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest that you create a plot with the outcome on the y-axis, `prob_diff` on the x-axis, and then you draw three lines (they will likely be curves) representing each of your conditions. You can do this by plugging in relevant values of `prob_diff` into the regression equation and calculating the probability of `choice`. I don't know if MATLAB has a function for doing this, but most statistical packages do. In other statsitical software, this goes by the general name of marginal effects calculation, although a quick internet search did not turn up anything like that for MATLAB.

See also [Interaction in generalized linear model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/49002/interaction-in-generalized-linear-model)

It appears that only the intercept is random in your model, which means that the probability of the outcome is shifted up or down for each subject but is mean 0 across all subjects. In other words, you don't need to worry about these when creating your interaction plot.

Comment: Won't it be difficult to interpret a plot with the outcome on the y axis, since it is binary ?

Comment: Possibly. You could try it both ways and see which makes the most sense. What I like about keeping the outcome on the y-axis is that if you extend the x-axis out far enough, the s-shape of the logistic curve will emerge.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused. How can there be any points on the y axis other than 0 and 1 ? Do you mean that we want to see a pattern of mostly 0s on the left and mosty 1s on the right ?

Comment: Yes. There will of course be a lot of points that move toward the middle, but if the association is strong enough, you will see some separation.